# I just want my development branch to prevail (over master), I don't want to resolve any conflicts

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-branch, git-merge

I have two branches, `master` and `development`.

When trying to merge `development` into `master` with `git merge development`, I get loads of conflicts.

I'm not interested in resolving any conflicts, I just want the `master` branch to be an exact replica of `development` - how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ***Please make sure your working copy is clean, and you've committed all your work, before doing this.***

"`I just want the master branch to be an exact replica of development`"

Assuming you're working with just your local branches,

`git checkout master`

`git reset --hard development`

This can be a dangerous operation if you have uncommitted work, but if that's what you really want to do, this will do it.

Comment: +1. I believe this suggestion also blows away all history in `master` since it diverged from `development` too. Keep this in mind if history is important to you.